# Serving multiple ML models using mlflow in a single VM

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, databricks, mlflow

I have setup an mlflow service in a VM and I am able to serve the model using mlflow serve command.
Wanted to know if we can host multiple models in a single VM ?

I am using the below command to serve a model using mlflow in a vm.

command:

```
/mlflow models serve -m models:/$Model-Name/$Version --no-conda -p 443 -h 0.0.0.0
```

Above command creates a model serving and runs it on 443 port.
Is it possible to have an endpoint like below being created with model name in it ?

Current URL:
https://localhost:443/invocations

Expected URL:
https://localhost:443/model-name/invocations ?

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that **mlflow models serve** will only accept POST input to the /invocations path.
If you want something custom I would suggest:

1. [Seldon](https://mlserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
2. Create a simple Flask app to do it as illustrated in this blog [post](https://docs.faculty.ai/user-guide/experiments/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

OSS MLflow only serves one model.

While Databricks MLflow model server doesn't yet support first-class multi-model serving, you can use registered model versions to serve different models. Since all model versions are deployed in a Databricks model server, you can reference them as https://mycompany.com/model/me/1/invocations or https://mycompany.com/model/me/2/invocations.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `mlflow models serve` command twice on different ports - exposing each port to its own model in your VM setup. E.g., port 8001 is your RandomForest model and port 8002 is your TfIdf vectorizer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe an approach [like this](https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/serving-multiple-models-with-mlflow-8311ba7939c7) might work for you:

In that link the use custom model (Pyfunc) to serve multiple models using a single serving endpoint. They can select the model they want to get predictions from through parameters in the API request.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/machine-learning/model-serving/serve-multiple-models-to-serving-endpoint) you can also find an example published for Azure Databricks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an application that serves multiple ML models, I would recommend [BentoML](https://www.bentoml.com/) because it supports Mlflow models and ASGI apps built with FastAPI. This means that defining multiple endpoints is simple (see [link](https://docs.bentoml.org/en/latest/guides/server.html)).

In my experience, Seldon over-complicates many things, whereas BentoML provides the maximum configurability with minimum effort.